# Error in retainedges[dat$seg] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: spatstat

I am conducting linearK function for the observed point pattern on a linear network and I get the following error
`Error in retainedges[dat$seg] : invalid subscript type 'list'`
I do not understand what it means and how should I correct it.

On the traceback call, I get the following information

```
> traceback()
4: thinNetwork(x, retainvertices = subi)
3: countends(L, X[-j], D[-j, j], toler = toler)
2: linearKengine(X, r = r, ..., denom = denom, correction = correction, 
       ratio = ratio)
1: linearK(sl2)
```

Could someone help me on what this error means and how I can correct it.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide your dataset `sl2` so we can reproduce this? Or if you cannot disclose the data could you try to make a fake dataset with the same structure reproducing this error?

Comment: Thank you I put it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_2R6KanT3YIWTJoeWhnMGhCbjQ)

Comment: For future reference I suggest you try to only ask questions when you have interesting problems not just concerning two points in a big network, so I don't spend time downloading a 100+ MB R object and debug things for you just to analyse two points!

Comment: Thank you. I just sent a pattern where there is a problem. I was not deliberate in sending 2 point pattern. I am sorry. Other patterns on the same network have more than 80 and upto 700 points.

Comment: OK. That fine. Does `linearK` give an error for all patterns on this network? I think the issue is when a component of the network has no points. In this case it really makes sense to discard that part, and I guess `spatstat` should do this automatically in the future.

Comment: Yes, a few of them more. I discarded them by some reasoning, also just to reduce scope of my study. But among what is still left this is one of them. Because this also gives a problem in envelope with summary function - linearK, but in that case, the simulation retries and it gets successful. Sorry, I am not a student of spatial statistics, but I intuitively feel spatstat approach can solve some of my questions. so I bought the book and learning myself. Could you please tell me how you identified disconnected components so that I can delete them. I have access to QGIS if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network is a bit problematic since it is disconnected. It has one very big component with 3755 vertices and 5593 lines and then 5 small components with only 2 or 3 vertices and 1 or 2 lines that are not connected to anything else. In your example you have only two points in this big network (both occurring in the big component as far as I can tell). We might be able to handle this in future versions of `spatstat`, but for now I suggest you simply discard the small empty components. Then I think `linearK` works as expected for your example (although I doubt you find interesting information from a pattern of 2 points!).

To identify connected components of a linear network use `connected.linnet` with argument `what = "components"` then you get a list of connected components and you can use the big connected component to define a new `lpp` on a connected `linnet`. With your example you could do something like (noting that component number 1 is the main component):

```
comp <- connected(as.linnet(sl2), what = "comp")
sl2new <- lpp(as.ppp(sl2), comp[[1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Could you please tell me how I could identify these disconnected components (in R?) and not get into same problem and waste other people's precious time. I would really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer with connected component code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the instructions and take more care in my next questions.